# Change a select list dynamically after choosing one of the radio buttons with JSP

Tags: jsp

I'm building a web app with JSP/JavaBeans etc. Only started this stuff for about 3 weeks. Is it possible to do the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g7wzT/1/) with JSP?

Tried to get the value printed out on the JSP first to test out but gave me a null value.

```
<div id="order-sidebar">
    <h3>Select which you want to do:</h3>
            <input type="radio" value="buy" name="purchase" checked />Buy
            <input type="radio" value="rent" name="purchase" />Rent
        <%
            String choice = request.getParameter("purchase");
            out.println(choice);
        %>
</div><!-- end of order-sidebar -->
```

Comment: Scriplets are computed at compile time, you need ajax for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression Language (EL) statements and scriptlets in JSPs are executed on the server before the page is sent to the browser.

The radio button changes in response to user input. EL and scriptlets cannot detect this.

The only way to manage this with EL is to send a request to the server whenever the radio button changes. Sending such a request would have to be implemented with Javascript or Jquery.